# Signout page issue for Windows Authentication, configured Form Based Authentication in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication

I have implemented Forms based authentication and Windows authentication after reading soultion on google and found step by step solution in https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent

Everything is working fine when external user login and click "SignOut" it come back to same Custom Login Page.

But when windows user logins and then click "SignOut" then Error appears

> "Something went wrong...".

as mentioned I also set

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout"  -RelativePath /_layouts/Sp.Login.Custom/Login.aspx"    -WebApplication "your web application url"
```

but still having same issue

Comment: Can some one guide?